# Is there a netlib method similar to vdInvSqrt in intel MKL?

Tags: linux, linear-algebra, intel-mkl, netlib

The call to get the inverse square root of a matrix/vector using Intel MKL is

```
vdInvSqrt(numElements, inputArray, outputArray);
```

Are there other ways to perform this function using only `netlib` calls?

Comment: netlib has a bunch of different libraries, each of which do their own wildly varying things, mostly very old and dusty. Which one(s) are you using?

Comment: I'm using ESSL now; I have blas and lapack with C++. I'm trying to write this function instead of using MKL.